# Run Flask on 127.0.0.2, get error "Can't assign requested address"

Tags: python, flask

I heard that all the 127.x.x.x are loopback IPs. So I try to run Flask on 127.0.0.2 but It gets error "Can't assign requested address" instead. While it works fine on 127.0.0.1

So how can I run flask on 127.0.0.x ?

Comment: can you clarify, why you need to run your app on anything else than 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @NivisPluma I need It in case I want 2 servers running on the same port, for example, 127.0.0.1:80, 127.0.0.2:80

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your OS is a MacOS. MacOS using only `127.0.0.1` for loopback interface

But it is possible to assign `127.0.0.XX` aliases manually

[This article](https://superuser.com/questions/458875/how-do-you-get-loopback-addresses-other-than-127-0-0-1-to-work-on-os-x) has couple solutions how to do that

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I am looking for. And I try assigning the alias manually as shown in your article, and it works too.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe what you looking for is to expose flask api on a different host than localhost(127.0.0.1)
You can choose a different port
`app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=8888)`

Or host with machine hostname

```py
from socket import gethostname
gethostname()
```

For custom hostname, add it in /etc/hosts file, it probably already contains a line about 127.0.0.1, in which case you just add your alias to the list

```
127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain myappname
```

in app

```
app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'myappname:5000'
```

for public, you would need to configure a specific dns